# Retrieve block index after transaction is sent

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, nodes

I am a developer integrating Polkadot JS to my app. I am creating an offline transaction which I am sending via the Polkadot Api RPC. In return I get the txid, but it does not help me to retrieve the transaction once it is mined. I need to get the block index and the extrinsing index in the block that the transaction will be mined. I am using the HTTP provider, the websoccet will not work for me. Can you guide me in the right direction?

Best regards!

Comment: I am not sure how long the HTTP will still work. Why can you not use WS? Normally you would use the `signAndSend` which returns a promise.

Comment: I am not using signAndSend because I dont want to share the private keys. I want to use HTTP because it is stateless. Even if I use websocket how would that benefit me?

Answer (score 1):

If you just have transaction hash, note that is not a [unique identifier](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#unique-identifiers-for-extrinsics) for a transaction in Polkadot, check this [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/getting-from-addresses-by-passing-transaction-id-or-hash).

What you can do is a function with PolkadotJS that is [listening to the events](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/system-events/) to see where your transactions has been included.

Simple script:

```
// Subscribe to system events via storage
api.query.system.events((events) => {
  console.log(`\nReceived ${events.length} events:`);

  // Loop through the Vec<EventRecord>
  events.forEach((record) => {
    // Extract the phase, event and the event types
    const { event, phase } = record;
    const types = event.typeDef;
    console.log(event.toHuman());
  });
});
```

If as Oliver suggest you use signAndSend is easier, check [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/get-block-hash-from-transfer-in-polkadot-js-api/5835#5835) on StackExchange

Comment: Using the events is not an option for me nor sharing the private key / mnemonic of the wallet. Is there any way that with the transaction hash I can receive all transactions with this hash?